# crawler distributed over different geographical locations

Tags: python, web-crawler, nutch

I have a few desktop machines at different geographical locations.  I need to create a crawler with clients at each desktop machine and a central server where data is indexed.  Is it possible to create such a crawler in Nutch? Are there any alternatives. Python based crawlers would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Nutch like buffer suggested, there is a script on the [Nutch Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/MergeCrawl) that may be able to help you. You would just need to get the linkdb, crawldb, and segments from each system to the central server before doing this - I think attempting to access those resources remotely would take a long time during the indexing process.